# Polymer built-in way to use "sub-pages" and core-submenu?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to create a page with `core-submenu` (and therefore also "subpages" (not a real component)). But as I've seen around the web there's a "problem" with this, since a press on a `core-submenu` item will trigger the `selected` event even though naturally one only want it triggered when a child element is pressed on.

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162227/scripting-required-for-polymer-submenu-pages-navigation) which explain a method to achieve what I want, but this approach relies on ids on all the pages and `core-submenu` childs. I have no need to "loop"-generate my menu. By not using `core-submenu` everything is working without even the slightest javascript-code.

Is there some built-in support for core-pages and core-submenu that can be used? In otherwords: A way that does not require any (or minimal) use of javascript?

```
.
. //some code here
.    
<core-menu theme="core-light-theme" selected="{{selected}}" selectedItem={{item}}>
        <core-submenu icon="settings" label="Favorites">
          <core-item icon="https" label="Hello"></core-item>
          <core-item icon="https" label="World"></core-item>
        </core-submenu>
    </core-menu>
.
. //some code here
.
    <core-animated-pages transitions="cross-fade" selected="{{selected}}">
      <section id="page-1">
        <div cross-fade>Hello content</div>
      </section>
      <section id="page-2">
        <div cross-fade>World content</div>
      </section>
    </core-animated-pages>
.
. //some code here
.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use valueattr for ex:

```
<core-menu theme="core-light-theme">
    <core-submenu icon="settings" label="Favorites"  valueattr="number" selected="{{number}}">
      <core-item icon="https" label="Hello" number="0"></core-item>
      <core-item icon="https" label="World" number="1"></core-item>
    </core-submenu>
      <core-submenu icon="settings" label="Favorites2"  valueattr="number" selected="{{number}}">
      <core-item icon="https" label="Hello2" number="2"></core-item>
      <core-item icon="https" label="World2" number="3"></core-item>
    </core-submenu>
</core-menu>
  <core-animated-pages transitions="cross-fade" selected="{{number}}">
  <section id="page-1">
    <div cross-fade>Hello content - {{number}}</div>
  </section>
  <section id="page-2">
    <div cross-fade>World content - {{number}}</div>
  </section>
      <section id="page-3">
    <div cross-fade>Hello content - {{number}}</div>
  </section>
  <section id="page-4">
    <div cross-fade>World content - {{number}}</div>
  </section>  
</core-animated-pages>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution that didn't use any javascript!

Comment: It seems the {{number}}-value becomes null when the core-submenu is pressed and is not set to a correct value until a sub-item is actually is pressed. This null value is causing faulty behaviour. Is there anything that can be done to prevent this?

Comment: Add this `<core-menu valueattr='number'>` and this `<core-submenu number='{{number}}'>`. That should help

Comment: Thank you @wirlez but making those changes causes the second core-submenu not to respond at all. :/

Comment: what behavior you expect? you can add default selection if no core-item selected for ex: <core-animated-pages selected="{{number || 0}}">

Comment: I want the page to stay at the same page until a "sub-item" has actually been pressed. Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions. It's really new to me this whole thing!

Comment: Or possibly select the first child of the submenu that you just pressed.

Comment: select 1st item sub-menu (added mnumber like number): <core-menu valueattr="mnumber" selected="{{mnumber}}">...<core-submenu icon="settings" label="Favorites" mnumber="0"  valueattr="number" selected="{{number}}">...<core-submenu icon="settings" label="Favorites2"  valueattr="number" selected="{{number}}" mnumber="2">...<core-animated-pages selected="{{number || mnumber}}">. It's look's like hack and don't applicable to mulltilevel menu. Much better  use js. Just add number listener: numberChanged: function(oldnumber,newnumber) {if(newnumber == null) newnumber = oldnumber;}

Comment: Thank you for providing both solutions! As you said it seems a bit too hackish (or unreadable) to not use javascript for that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could dump the idea of having a "shared selected" and instead have something that respond on "core-select" event.

This will work just fine.

```
    <template is='auto-binding'>
    <core-scaffold>
        <core-header-panel navigation flex>
            <core-toolbar>Menu</core-toolbar>

            <core-menu on-core-select='{{navFunc}}'>

                <core-item label='page1'></core-item>

                <core-submenu label='something' type='submenu'>
                    <core-item label='page2'></core-item>
                    <core-item label='page3'></core-item>

                    <core-submenu label='super submenu' type='submenu'>
                        <core-item label='page4'></core-item>
                        <core-item label='page5'></core-item>
                    </core-submenu>

                </core-submenu>

                <core-submenu label='more here' type='submenu'>
                    <core-item label='page6'></core-item>
                    <core-item label='page7'></core-item>
                </core-submenu>

            </core-menu>

        </core-header-panel>

        <core-animated-pages selected='{{myselection}}' valueattr='label'>
            <section label='page1'>Page1</section>
            <section label='page2'>Page2</section>
            <section label='page3'>Page3</section>
            <section label='page4'>Page4</section>
            <section label='page5'>Page5</section>
            <section label='page6'>Page6</section>
            <section label='page7'>Page7</section>
        </core-animated-pages>

    </core-scaffold>
    </template>
    <script>
        var template = document.querySelector('template[is="auto-binding"]');

        template.navFunc = function(e, detail){
            if (detail.item.getAttribute('type') !== 'submenu' && detail.isSelected == true) {
                template.myselection = detail.item.getAttribute('label');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I think I will use a hybrid of this and the other answer posted. I didn't know about the valueattr-property that could be used! I will however accept the other answer since it actually contains no javascript as I requested.

Comment: feel free to come back when you notice that his solution isn't working correctly :)

Comment: Well he forgot some attributes on some places but it _almost_ works as intended. There's the issue as I commented on his post. But I still feel like I shouldn't need the javascript! :)